# Service vs Thread

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

What should I use to make an application that will:

1. Ask the user for username and password
2. Authorize
3. Run an **infinite** loop in which it will fetch some data from the website every 10 seconds or so.

I want to be able to do some basic tasks in the meantime, or lock my screen without the thread getting killed. I don't want the service to continue running after I close the application, I just want to be sure the thread is never killed while it's running for a long time.

I also wanted to ask: Are services as easy to interact with as threads? Can I just pass a `CancellationToken` in it and cancel it when the user presses the stop button?

I also found the `setThreadPriority`, will it help in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services and Threads are totally different concepts.  A Thread is a separate process that executes in parallel.  A Service is a component of an app that doesn't have a UI and runs with a separate life cycle.  A service does not run on its own thread, it runs on the UI thread (although it can launch a Thread if it wishes).

You use a Service if you want to do some task but not be bound to the Android Activity lifecycle.  You use a Thread if you want to run in parallel.  If you want both, then you use a Service that launches a Thread.

From what I'm reading (you don't want the Thread to continue after the Activity is finished), you want a Thread and not a Service.

Comment: will a thread run infinite if I don't do anything resource expensive?

Comment: A thread runs until the thread's function returns or the application exits.  Please note-  the Application exits, not the Activity.  Just finishing the Activity will not kill the Thread, you need to cancel it when your Activity is destroyed so it can exit itself.

Comment: > _A thread runs until the thread's function returns or the application exits._ That is true but [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) states that: A process holding an activity that's not currently visible to the user have no direct impact on the user experience, and the system can kill them at any time to reclaim memory for a foreground, visible, or service process.

Comment: @sooqua That's true.  But that's true of anything.  Any app that isn't currently the foreground app can be ended at any time if the OS decides it needs its resources.  There is no avoiding that.

Comment: Ok, then I'll go with threads and hope that Android won't decide to kill it at some point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A service can run in isolation (while your app is not necessarily running). A thread can be spun off from either your app itself, or a service.

Comment: But I want the opposite of "isolation". I want to interact with it just as I do with threads. And it doesn't need to continue to run after I close my app. I just need this job running no matter what and I'm trying to find the best way to do that

Comment: You might want to check out [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). These serve as services that your activities can interact with. Maybe this will help