# Services, threads, and process

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, process, android-service

In a [recent  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672516/1440565), I read

> A service does not run on its own thread, it runs on the UI thread

I've read similar statements in many other service-related questions.

If I call `startService()` from an `Activity`, will the `Service` run on the `Activity`'s UI `Thread` or does it spawn a new process with it's own UI `Thread`?

If it runs on the `Activity`'s UI `Thread`, doesn't that risk making the `Activity` unresponsive?

Answer (score 3):

Yes services does run on main thread , About ANR(application not responding ) concern , there will higher chances of ANRs if your service is doing a long processing work using CPU so the official docs also recommends to use `Worker Threads` for efficiency. [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

You must read the **caution**  paragraph in the docs to confirm

If your task is one time shot then Use `IntentService` which implicitly use threading mechanism for processing but `IntentService` will destroy itself automatically when the task is done so you will have to start it again for the next time and so.

**android:process** :  Using this to start a service in an another process will cause usage of more memory. This will cause creating two processes for your app in separate heap memory space which also require other maintenance as well.So this is rarely used and i would not recommend to use this for a regular service task.

Comment: whoever down vote this please leave a comment with reason

Answer (score 2):

> If I call `startService()` from an `Activity`, will the `Service` run on
>   the `Activity`'s UI `Thread` or does it spawn a new process with it's
>   own UI `Thread`?

If it's a `Service` (not an `IntentService`), it will run on the main `Thread` of your app's process, as long as you do not define it as a separate process explicitly (by adding the `android:process` tag in the Manifest).

> If it runs on the `Activity`'s UI `Thread`, doesn't that risk making the
>   `Activity` unresponsive?

Yes it does, if you perform CPU intensive/blocking operations.

To prevent that, you can either start new `Thread`(s) from your `Service`, or use an `IntentService`, which will automatically spawn a new worker `Thread` for its work.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Services Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) it clearly explains your answer.

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

Answer (score 1):

> In a recent answer, I read
>
> ```
>  A service does not run on its own thread, it runs on the UI thread
> ```

This is just plain wrong. A `Service` is an object (an instance of a class). It doesn't run on any thread, it doesn't run at all. It just "is". The methods of the `Service` may run on any thread, depending...

Specifically, the lifecycle methods of a `Service` (`onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, etc.) that are called directly from the Android framework run on the main (UI) thread, which may or may not be the same thread that called `startService()`. However, a `Service` can (and usually does) start other background threads, as many as it needs to, to perform the necessary work.

> If I call startService() from an Activity, will the Service run on the
>   Activity's UI Thread or does it spawn a new process with it's own UI
>   Thread?

See above. If you want your `Service` to run in a separate process, you can do this by specifying `android:process=":service"` in the `<service>` declaration in the manifest. By default, services run in the same process as the other components (`Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.) of your application.

> If it runs on the Activity's UI Thread, doesn't that risk making the
>   Activity unresponsive?

That depends on what your `Service` is doing! Obviously if your `Service` is doing a lot of compute-intensive processing on the UI thread it will make your app unresponsive. If your `Service` is doing I/O on the UI thread, Android will usually throw exceptions (in more recent versions of Android). This is the reason that services usually start background threads to do work. However, if your `Service` is lightweight, then there is no reason why methods of your `Service` cannot run on the UI thread. As I said, it depends...

Comment: "This is just plain wrong..." I think you are being a bit pedantic here. The word "service" can have multiple meanings depending on the context and capitalization. `Service` is a class, certainly, and we can create instances of this class. However, I think "service" can validly refer to the executable code in memory which is essentially the methods the lifecycle methods and the methods they call.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry, but I have to disagree. In Android, `Service` is a very specific and important concept/component. My comments may sound pedantic to you, but there are literally thousands of Android developers who do not have even a basic understanding of what these components are and how they actually work. The only way to "clear the air" and bring some sanity back to Android development, is to fight this misinformation at every chance.

Comment: Also, if you look at the question/answer you linked to, it is very clear that the person is referring to an Android `Service` (the component), and not a general computing concept.

Answer (score 0):

IntentService runs on the background thread, so, if you want to do one-off tasks then use that.

Comment: `IntentService` doesn't run on the background thread. The lifecycle methods of `IntentService` run on the main (UI) thread, just the same as the lifecycle methods of all services. `IntentService` creates one (or more) worker threads, which are used to "do the work" of the `IntentService`, through the call to `onHandleIntent()` (which is called on the worker thread, not on the main (UI) thread). However, `IntentService` is not always the best solution to the problem, so to suggest that OP use `IntentService` without knowing anything about his application, is not helpful.